# copy file error - object required: quotes

Tags: file, vbscript, copy

I am trying to create a script that would copy a file from a USB onto my computer. It would search for a USB, and use that as the drive letter.
I got some third-party software that would allow me to eject the USB once it was done. I think that everything was fine except for the copy line. I have looked at numerous StackOverflow posts, but none seemed to have the answer.

The error was:

> Object Required: "

My code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO, objDrive, scriptBaseName
Dim WshShell, strUserName, fso, x, v, y
Set objFSO     = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
scriptBaseName = objFSO.GetBaseName(Wscript.ScriptFullName)
For Each objDrive In objFSO.Drives
  If objDrive.DriveType = 1 And objDrive.IsReady Then
    MsgBox objDrive.DriveLetter & ":\ = " & objDrive.VolumeName, vbInformation, scriptBaseName
  End If
Next

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strUserName = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%")

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

x = objDrive.DriveLetter & ":\Inspirational\Inspirational_Quotes.VBS"
v = "C:\Users\" & strUserName & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"

'Below was the problem
fso.CopyFile x, v, True
```

I tried this:

```
y = "Inspirational\Inspirational_Quotes.VBS"
WScript.Echo objDrive.DriveLetter & ":\" & y
```

I am not sure what I have to do to fix the error though.

Then, I just had to remove the USB

```
'Remove the USB'(s)
WshShell.Run "D:\Inspirational\removedrive\x64\RemoveDrive_D"
WshShell.Run "D:\Inspirational\removedrive\x64\RemoveDrive_E"
```

I experimented with this:

```
fso.CopyFile """" & x & """", """" & v & """", True
```

But it still didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to escape the backslashes? Have you tried to add escaped quotation signs to your argument?

Comment: Inside the `for` loop save the `objDrive.DriveLetter` property into a variable and use this variable when initializing `x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objDrive` is your loop variable. It doesn't retain a value/object after the loop finishes. You need to assign the value or object to another variable to make it accessible outside the loop.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each objDrive In fso.Drives
  If objDrive.DriveType = 1 And objDrive.IsReady Then
    path = objDrive.RootFolder.Path
  End If
Next

x = fso.BuildPath(path, "Inspirational\Inspirational_Quotes.VBS")
```

Quotes don't have anything to do with the problem. `FileSystemObject` methods can handle paths with spaces just fine without additional quotes.

You don't need to create multiple `FileSystemObject` objects, BTW. Just create the object once at the beginning of your script.

Comment: I tried it, and it worked perfectly! Thank you for solving my problem!